# How to fix MacBook Air tried almost everything to reinstall Mac OS X

Tags: mac, reinstall, reset, macbook-air

On start up I get the flashing grey file with question mark sign. I’ve tried pretty much everything I e seen while researching answers to my problem. And always end up at the same place, staring at “an error occurred while preparing installation. Try running this application again.”

[image: Screenshot of flashing grey file with question mark sign]

Comment: Hi antwan, welcome to SuperUser. Please edit your Question post to include enough technical information to give us something to go on. Exactly which model of MBA? Also, tell us what you've tried so far, so we know what not to suggest. For future reference, check out "[How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". It's a bit dated, but it covers all the bases of how to ask technical questions well so you get good answers quickly.

Comment: There's also the [Ask Different question checklist](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3387/ask-different-question-checklist)